# Matlab: Multiplying select rows every nth interval

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication

I have a 63row x 7column matrix.

```
xmax=63;
ymax=7;

for i=1:xmax
    for j=1:ymax
        n=(i-1)*ymax+j;
        matrix(i,j)=n;

    end
end


    1     2     3     4     5     6     7
    8     9    10    11    12    13    14
   15    16    17    18    19    20    21
   22    23    24    25    26    27    28
   29    30    31    32    33    34    35
   36    37    38    39    40    41    42
   43    44    45    46    47    48    49
   50    51    52    53    54    55    56
   57    58    59    60    61    62    63
   64    65    66    67    68    69    70
   71    72    73    74    75    76    77
   78    79    80    81    82    83    84
   85    86    87    88    89    90    91
   92    93    94    95    96    97    98
   99   100   101   102   103   104   105
**106** 107   108   109   110   111 **112**
**113** 114   115   116   117   118 **119**
**120** 121   122   123   124   125 **126**
  127   128   129   130   131   132   133
  134   135   136   137   138   139   140
  141   142   143   144   145   146   147
  148   149   150   151   152   153   154
  155   156   157   158   159   160   161
  162   163   164   165   166   167   168
**169** 170   171   172   173   174 **175**
**176** 177   178   179   180   181 **182**
**183** 184   185   186   187   188 **189**
  190   191   192   193   194   195   196
  197   198   199   200   201   202   203
  204   205   206   207   208   209   210
  211   212   213   214   215   216   217
  218   219   220   221   222   223   224
  225   226   227   228   229   230   231
**232** 233   234   235   236   237 **238**
**239** 240   241   242   243   244 **245**
**246** 247   248   249   250   251 **252**
  253   254   255   256   257   258   259
  260   261   262   263   264   265   266
  267   268   269   270   271   272   273
  274   275   276   277   278   279   280
  281   282   283   284   285   286   287
  288   289   290   291   292   293   294
**295** 296   297   298   299   300 **301**
**302** 303   304   305   306   307 **308**
**309** 310   311   312   313   314 **315**
  316   317   318   319   320   321   322
  323   324   325   326   327   328   329
  330   331   332   333   334   335   336
  337   338   339   340   341   342   343
  344   345   346   347   348   349   350
  351   352   353   354   355   356   357
**358** 359   360   361   362   363 **364**
**365** 366   367   368   369   370 **371**
**372** 373   374   375   376   377 **378**
  379   380   381   382   383   384   385
  386   387   388   389   390   391   392
  393   394   395   396   397   398   399
  400   401   402   403   404   405   406
  407   408   409   410   411   412   413
  414   415   416   417   418   419   420
  421   422   423   424   425   426   427
  428   429   430   431   432   433   434
  435   436   437   438   439   440   441
```

I want to change the values that have asterisks around them.

If you count down the two columns in groups of 9...they are every (7th 8th and 9th) group entry of each column.

I would like to be able to select these values using this format of code or similar:

```
maxi=63;
maxj=7;

for j=1:t
    for n=1:maxi
        for m=1:maxj
           if m==1  
          *insert code here*
           if m==maxj
          *insert code here......etc*
```

I would not like to select the first 7th 8th 9th value nor the last 3 values (so I'd like to ignore the first 9 grouping and the last 9 grouping).

I can do this manually for each entry but the difficulty lies in being able to do it automatically when I change the size of the matrix. For whatever size, the code should run down the first column and last column at every 16,17,18th and 25,26,27th etc.. and stops before the last three entries (or the last grouping of 9) whilst skipping over the 7,8,9th.

I'm eventually going to multiply the values in the asterisked cells by 2 and replace the adjacent column's value with it.

So

for column 1, if m==1, m+1 = column1*2

for column 7, if m==maxj, m-1 = column7*2

I am aware that mod allows for use of multiples but I am still running into the same problems when I change the matrix size.

Difficult problem to state. Please tell me how I should clarify it and many thanks for your patience and time.

Comment: Just a side note: you can generate your matrix without explicitly looping with `matrix = reshape(1:xmax*ymax, ymax, xmax)';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automatically adjust your "maxi" and "maxj" with the following:

```
[maxi, maxj] = size(matrix);
```

However, using for loops in Matlab generally gives bad performance, and frankly, the code is a little ugly.  I would try to go with something more along the lines of:

```
period = 9;
matrix(16:period:end-period, 2) = 2 * matrix(16:period:end-period, 1);
matrix(17:period:end-period, 2) = 2 * matrix(17:period:end-period, 1);
matrix(18:period:end-period, 2) = 2 * matrix(18:period:end-period, 1);
```

Please understand that I have not carefully checked the above for correctness.  In particular I would look at how it does or doesn't do the last group of 3.

Comment: Adding the column dimension to this code makes it work quite well.

Answer (score 1):

As Jim Clay suggests, you don't need any loops for this.

```
[m,n] = size(A);
k = 9;
idx = [16:k:m-k 17:k:m-k 18:k:m-k];
A(idx,2) = 2 * A(idx,1);
```

If you want to neglect more indices, say `[1 3 5]`, just remove them from `idx` before the multiplication:

```
idx = setdiff(idx, [1 3 5]);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful suggestion. I will definitely read into this. I relisted this question in a much clearer format after your earlier comment :)